# How to give discount on new Stripe subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

We have a free subscription concept separate from Stripe. When a user signs up for a paid subscription we want to charge them immediately but still honor any remaining free-period.

I know I can use trial period to delay the start of the Stripe subscription, but we wanted to charge immediately to confirm valid credit card details. Is it possible to give a discount on a new subscription instead, to account for the users remaining free-time?

For example, if

- today is the 1st
- user has free subscription until 15th
- monthly subscription is $10

I would like to charge them $5 today and immediately begin their subscription in Stripe with a Stripe renewal on the next 1st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to [add an invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items) for the amount you want to charge and set a trial period until you want the renewing charge to occur (so in your example you set a [trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_end) for the next 1st of month). This will generate an initial invoice with the invoice item and then set your recurring payment as you desire.